# Windows 7 requires UAC elevation for VB6 application (Vista did not)

Tags: vb6, windows-7, uac, manifest

I have an old VB6 application which should run on Windows 7 (with UAV set to the default level, 3 of 4 IMHO). It has the functionality to update itself, and Windows 7 is now complaining that it would modify the computer (At least windows 7 is right here).

I was able to run it in Vista with some kind of manifest file, but this does not seem to work anymore (which is the intended behaviour if I think of it).

The manifest file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.1.0.24" processorArchitecture="X86" name="IKOfficeAppStarter" type="win32"/>
    <description>IKOffice Starter</description>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
             version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" 
             publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

The manifest can be found near the exe "IKOffice Starter.exe" and is called "IKOffice Starter.exe.manifest", which should be okey.

Currently the Shield Icon has gone from my .exe, but when try to start the software, i get the message "Der angeforderte Vorgang erfordert höhere Rechte", or translated to english "the requested operation requires elevation".

What can I do to stop windows to bug me anymore, so I can install this application on our clients computers. Hey, I already told Windows to run it as Invoker, so why is it still complaining?

Comment: The asInvoker setting means "this process should inherit the security token of the process that started it."  Did you want requireAdministrator instead?

Comment: No, I just wanted to make windows to let the program fail instead of bugging me we a message box

Answer (score 1):

Where does that error message come from? Windows or your VB6 app? Could the VB6 app be saying "hey, you're running me as invoker but I need to be run elevated?" After all, VS2008 does that. Or do you think Windows is saying that to you?

Also I doubt you need `uiAccess=true` and since manifests tend to get copied from project to project, make it false.